# Windows Phone 8.1 Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, paypal, windows-phone-8.1, payment-gateway

Looking for some help regarding Paypal payment gateway integration using Windows Phone 8.1.
Paypal doesn't have any support for 8.1 devices yet. They have a sample application targeting Windows Phone 8 [here](https://github.com/paypal/windows8-sample-apps) . But the Paypal checkout dll used there is not compatible with Windows Phone 8.1.

Few questions ,

1. Are there any Windows Phone 8.1 applications which depend on Paypal for making payments.
2. If yes , then how are these applications working ?
3. Are there any other payment gateways which are supported in windows phone 8.1 ?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just build the API calls into your Windows Phone app directly as opposed to relying on an SDK to do it for you.  I would recommend using [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/), which consists of 3 API calls.

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

Express Checkout will automatically use a mobile experience when it detects a mobile browser.